# Change RDA aesthetically better

Tags: r, rda

I would like to improve aesthetically my RDA plot,
For example, I would like to change my black triangles to a text labels or other options that could improve my RDA plot:
This is the code and data that I am using:

```
ordiplot(p1)
points(p1, "sites", pch=17, col="black")
```

the red crosses are species and triangles are each "site"
I can't share my data because contain more than 2000 species,
but all idea its appreciate :D

[image]

Comment: Since you chose black triangles, you must like those.   What is it you don't like about the plot now?

Comment: You don't have to share your data to share a [mcve]. For example, you could start with the example from `?vegan::ordiplot` and make it look like the plot above (and post the code) ...